# Spring Jpa query using more join between table

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

i m a newbie of Spring. I'm working on my project using Spring Data Jpa. I have three entity with these relation:

1. City
2. Customer
3. Orders

The relation are :

- one orders one customer. One customer many orders ( 1->n)
- one customer one city. One city more customers ( 1->n)

I have to develop a function that should find all the orders related to customer of a specified city.
In Oracle sql I would write the following query

```
select o.order_number from orders o, customers c, city ci
 where ci.city_name='NEW YORK' and ci.id_city=c.id_city and o.customer_id=c.id_customer
```

How can do this using spring data Jpa ? I m able write in my interface city repository a method to find city entities that have city_name='NEW YORK' but i m not able to write in order repository a method that do the query reported above.
Thanks

Comment: If `Order` entity has a `customer` property and `Customer` entity has a `city` property, `List<Order> findAllByCustomerCityName(String city)` on `OrderRepository` should be sufficient.

Comment: Sample application added on [Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/41505417) to see `findAllByCustomerCityName` in action.

Comment: @manish go ahead and make this an answer